# What happens if MyBatis SqlSession is not closed for long time?

Tags: java, database, db2, database-connection, mybatis

Why does `DisconnectNonTransientException` occur? It happened only once and the error could not be reproduced after that. What is the fix to avoid the error from occurring in future. More importantly how to fix an issue that is no longer reproducible?

**edit:** More updates on this question.

1. Using mybatis,DB2,tomcat.(trying to access remote DB)
2. This error occurs when code hits data source for first time after a long gap since the application in tomcat was last accessed. When refreshed, error disappears and the application works as expected.
3. Connection to data source is closed after every access
4. SqlSession created is not closed(Does this cause the trouble?)
5. Error says : `"The database manager is not able to accept new requests, has terminated all requests in progress, or has terminated this particular request due to unexpected error conditions detected at the target system. ERRORCODE=-4499, SQLSTATE=58009"`

Is there any default timeout for mybatis `SqlSession`?

Comment: If it happened only once, chances are that it was a network blip, a firewall change/reboot, a temporary outage of some component in the chain. You have to find root cause before you can talk about a fix.

Comment: But how to find a root cause? The stacktrace was pointing to mybatis class. @mao

Comment: Edit your question to post the full stacktrace. If it was a network blip, you have to involve the people who manage the network between your app and the target server.

Answer (score 0):

> More importantly how to fix an issue that is no longer reproducible?

In the stacktrace you can find where the exception is thrown. Then debugging the code you can find why it's thrown.

Many exceptions occurs because something wrong with the code or with the data. You should find what is wrong and fix it. If you can't fix it in the code where it occurred then you catch the exception from your code and then decide what to do with it.

If you can't reproduce the exception then you can trace the code that may throw the exception. Show or write the debugging code by changing the logging mode.

If you got the exception stacktrace then you should be aware what the code was when it thrown.

If you have some tests that might reproduce the exception then you can write additional code to intercept the exception. You should write such code trying to reproduce the exception on the test environment. Then you should know how to handle it.